# Does not get data from Arduino - bluetooth to Android Device

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I want to communication between Arduino with Bluetooth and Android Device

In Arduino, I am using

```
 SoftwareSerial.h
```

and below is the code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
int ledPin1 = 5;
int state = 0;
int flag = 0;
SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1);
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);

digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);

Serial.begin(9600);
mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    if(Serial.available()>0){
      state = Serial.read();
      flag = 0;
    }
    if (mySerial.available()) {
      int k = mySerial.read();
      mySerial.write(k);
    }
}
```

and from Android side I am using [BluetoothSPPLibrary](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary)

there is class named BluetoothService.java

in that there is ConnectedThread

```
 public void run()
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: Called");
            byte[] buffer;
            ArrayList<Integer> arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    int data = mmInStream.read();
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: "+data);
                    if(data == 0x0A) { 
                    } else if(data == 0x0D) {
                        buffer = new byte[arr_byte.size()];
                        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr_byte.size() ; i++) {
                            buffer[i] = arr_byte.get(i).byteValue();
                        }
                        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothState.MESSAGE_READ
                                , buffer.length, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                        arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    } else {
                        arr_byte.add(data);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothService.this.start(BluetoothService.this.isAndroid);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

but

```
 int data = mmInStream.read();
```

here data is not coming from above code

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some information here. Which Arduino board are you using? Based on the fact you're trying to send bluetooth using a Serial connection, I'm assuming you have an external bluetooth chip/board, which is it? If you are using one are you absolutely sure it's wired correctly. Is it using Bluetooth or Bluetooth Low Energy, the two have very different protocols. That information will help.

Comment: How does this help OP's question ?

Comment: This helps because the communication protocol differs significantly between Bluetooth and BluetoothLE so receiving the information on the android side would be different. Also, how can we say that the Arduino code is accurate without having any idea which bluetooth chip he is using? Also, what if he doesn't have the chip wired correctly?